# How to show a plain text value on admin ui form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, ui-form

I have create a ui form. The data is getting inserted successfully. Now i want to edit the form, but i want only certain field to get edited not all.

The remaining field should be shown in a simple plain text.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: yes below is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that field read only by disbling it.

You have to just add more below line in your form field code

```
       <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

for notice vendor\module\view\base\web\templates\form
create field-html-notice.html

with below code

```
<div class="admin__field"
 visible="visible"
 css="$data.additionalClasses"
 attr="'data-index': index">
<label class="admin__field-label" if="$data.label" visible="$data.labelVisible" attr="for: uid">
    <span translate="label" attr="'data-config-scope': $data.scopeLabel"/>
</label>
<div class="admin__field-control"
     css="'_with-tooltip': $data.tooltip, '_with-reset': $data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault">
    <render args="elementTmpl" ifnot="hasAddons()"/>

    <div class="admin__control-addon" if="hasAddons()">
        <render args="elementTmpl"/>

        <label class="admin__addon-prefix" if="$data.addbefore" attr="for: uid">
            <span text="addbefore"/>
        </label>
        <label class="admin__addon-suffix" if="$data.addafter" attr="for: uid">
            <span text="addafter"/>
        </label>
    </div>

    <render args="tooltipTpl" if="$data.tooltip"/>

    <render args="fallbackResetTpl" if="$data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault"/>

    <label class="admin__field-error" if="error" attr="for: uid" text="error"/>

  <!--   <div class="admin__field-note" if="$data.notice" attr="id: noticeId">
        <span translate="notice"/>
    </div>

    <div class="admin__additional-info" if="$data.additionalInfo" html="$data.additionalInfo"></div>

    <!-- view/base/web/template/form/field-html-notice.html:35 -->
  <div class="admin__field-note" if="$data.notice" attr="id: noticeId" html="$data.notice"></div>

  <div class="admin__additional-info" if="$data.additionalInfo" html="$data.additionalInfo"></div>

    <render args="$data.service.template" if="$data.hasService()"/>
</div>
```

and add in your ui-form below filed like:

```
          <field name="test_filed_name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subscription Period</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">model</item>
               <item name="additionalInfo" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
                ${ $.provider }:data.test_filed_name                 
                </item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">subscription_period</item>
         </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

please try this i am not sure about ${ $.provider }:data.test_filed_name

Comment: That's a last option.

Comment: Means?  You don't  want to disabled?

Comment: I just want to show them like 
<label>Abc :</label> <span>Value</span>

Comment: Then you can refer customer address grid may be it can help you

Comment: Then we can set that value as like notice... but we can not get that value when we submit the form @avesh

Comment: Ya i don't want those values on save controller. I won't be saving them.

Comment: @AveshNaik i have edited ans please check if it can any help to you

Comment: can we call any classes to get the value for that input dynamically? like <field name="test_filed_name" class="some_class">

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, tried this in different way, can you post your answer for it? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249369/product-edit-form-issue-in-admin-panel-magento2

Answer (score 4):

```
<field formElement="input" name="field_name">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Field label</label>
        <dataScope>field name</dataScope>
        <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/text</elementTmpl>
    </settings>
</field>
```

This makes it as you want: just label + text instead of input field