# Update JS in core magento commands to make them work

Tags: magento2

Maybe a stupid question, but the answers i can find are all differtent.

I changed some JS in core magento (vendor/magento), what CLI commands i need to make them effective? Is below correct (magento 2.2 with redis cache)

```
rm -rf generated/code* generated/metadata* var/view_preprocessed/*; rm -R pub/static/*;

php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL && php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no good to use **rm -rf** (it removes the .htaccess file ), run the second row commands so it can generate by itself :

```
php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL && php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If that doesn`t show your updates , it means you have an additional cache configured to clean , flush that and will be ok .

Comment: So the removall or empty of the folders is not nescessary at all?

Comment: Not necessary at all , thats why the commands are made for . I haven`t seen that magento 2 doc suggest using rm -rf for that ;) .

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli, Please post your answer to here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249369/product-edit-form-issue-in-admin-panel-magento2

Comment: Sorry @jafarpinjar i didnt understood you . What do you mean ?

Comment: can you update your answer for that issue?