# how can I get an image to be used in mobile app by rest api

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I've written the following function

```
public function getImg($sku){
    $product=$this->productRepository->get($sku);
    $image=$product->getImage();

    return $image;
}
```

as an api method and it returns me the name of the image.
how can I get an image to be used and viewed in mobile app by rest api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get media url first then concat this before image url. You can get media url from below code

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager

) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
public function getMediaUrl() {
   $mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
}
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: @Ramkishan, Please check and post your thoughts here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249369/product-edit-form-issue-in-admin-panel-magento2

Comment: @yomna welcome :)

Comment: Sure @jafar I will check

Comment: Thanks @Ramkishan, That would be a great help!!

Comment: @Ramkishan, could you check my issue? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249425/custom-field-in-product-edit-form-in-magento2-admin