# Custom Field in Product Edit form in magento2 admin

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, data-provider, addfield, modifier

I am trying to add custom text field in product edit form in admin panel.

I have used below code in etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
   <virtualType 
   name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customTab" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">
                    Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\NewField
                </item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

And used below code in Newfield.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
 use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
 use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
 use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
 use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
 use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
 class NewField extends AbstractModifier
{
private $locator;
protected $_coreRegistry;
protected $_resource;
private $stockRegistry;
public function __construct(
    LocatorInterface $locator,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry  $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
) {
    $this->locator = $locator;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}
public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    return $data;
}

public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
        $meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                'custom_fieldset' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('Actual Quantity'),
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => 'data.product.custom_fieldset',
                                'collapsible' => false,
                                'sortOrder' => 5,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                    'custom_field' => $this->getCustomField()
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        );
        return $meta;
    }

public function getCustomField()
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Actual Qty'),
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => 'enabled',
                    'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => 10,
                    'value' => $this->getProductData(),
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function getConnection()
{
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    return $connection;
}
public function getProductData()
{
    $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $sql = "select SUM(a.qty) as qty from quote_item as a join quote as b ON a.quote_id = b.entity_id 
                    where b.reserved_order_id is NULL and b.is_active = '1' and a.product_id = '".$productId."'";
    $resultSets = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
    if(isset($resultSets[0]['qty'])){
        $actualQty = $resultSets[0]['qty'];
        return $actualQty;
    }else{
        $productStock = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
        $productQty = $productStock->getQty();
        return $productQty;
       }

    }

 }
```

The text field is created in product edit form but i am looking for code how to move it after the Qty field. Now it has been created with separate field set.

Is it possible to move to after the qty field? Or is there any other methods to do that? Please anybody help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Why are you not doing this from product attribute which you can create from admin?

Comment: Yes, but the value we need to show on the fly, if attribute created value we need to pass manually?

Comment: Ok it means you want that field value should be pre-filled. Is it so?

Comment: yes, the value is returned from the function i written there getProductData(), That is also coming now, but only thing that has to move inside product detail tab, instead of creating new fieldset

Comment: You should create new attribute from admin and add this in attribute set. Then you should implement login in modifier class as you are doing.

Comment: not cleared about your point, am i doing wrong in the question i posted? Can you please update me in code what you are suggesting here

Comment: @Ramkishan, Attribute i created and assigned to attribute set, but the value how can i set from query result?

Comment: You can add a load before to set Data on Product object and set your Attribute Data in it on the same index as your product Attribute Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set default value from below code. Update modifyMeta function from like this.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager $arrayManager
) {
    $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
}

public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    $fieldCode = 'custom_fieldset';
    $elementPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath($fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');
    $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(static::CONTAINER_PREFIX . $fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');
    if (!$elementPath) {
        return $meta;
    }

    $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
        $containerPath,
        $meta,
        [
            'children'  => [
                $fieldCode => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'required'  => false,
                                'default'  => $this->getProductData()
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
 return $meta;
}
```

Let me know if you face any issue while doing this.

Comment: Hello Ramkishan, what is ArrayManager? which class i need to use to construct? this one use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;?

Comment: I updated my answer please check.

Comment: Yes @Ramkishan, used your code , but my field is disappeared from product view form.

Comment: product view form?

Comment: Edit form, like when i open the product in admin panel, I can't see the new field over there,

Comment: sorry i got it, it was my mistake I forgot to return $meta. Please check updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85536/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-ramkishan).

Comment: This will work as soon as we open the edit form of product, or once we save the product. for me its working when i open and save the product. not when the product is opened.

Comment: It's working perfectly. Perfect answer.

Comment: Great to hear :)

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar, can we add tooltip for the field?