# Magento 2: How to add additional % to all products

Tags: magento2

I want to add catalog rule example: add +10% to all products.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

***Catalog rule does not increase the price of a product, it decreases the price of the product***. So, using **increase product price 10% by catalog price is not the right idea**.

So, It is an idea if you will ***increase product  price by 10% at product level*** mean at product edit page then **apply 9.09%  discount from catalog rule**

Comment: hi @Amit, Thanks, could you please help with this issue, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249425/custom-field-in-product-edit-form-in-magento2-admin

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible through the creation of a plugin.

Look into plugin development here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

You could create an interceptor that adds 10% to all prices.