# How to get product image path by product id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, image

Hello friends i want to fetch image path like var/www/magento/pub/media
i wand to display image in admin grid i am  using rendarar to get image
image path by passing Product id. How this can be achieved ? please explain

thanks 
Adarsh Shukla

Comment: please refer to this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249393/how-can-i-get-an-image-to-be-used-in-mobile-app-by-rest-api/249395#249395

Comment: hello sir thanks for reply but but i was looking for path not url

Comment: plaease tell me how to do so

Comment: ok you mean absolute path?

Comment: yes sir like var/www/magento/pub/media

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get media absolute path you can try below code.

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList

) {
    $this->directory = $directoryList;
}
public function getMediaAbsoluteUrl() {
   $mediaAbsoluteUrl = $this->directory->getPath('media');
}
```

I hope it'll work for you.

Comment: Will This give me product image path by product id ?

Comment: it will written absolute path of media directory as per you mentioned in comments.

Comment: is my aim is to get products image by passing product id i am trying to display that image to admin grid

Comment: I am not able to get you, like why you need absolute url for this. If you just need to display product image then link which I have share in starting will work for you.

Comment: You just need to append $product->getImage() after $mediaUrl

Answer (score 4):

Add this below code in your file :

```
protected $_imageHelper;
protected $_productRepositoryFactory;
public function __construct(
    .........................
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory,
    .........................
)
{
    .........................
    $this->_imageHelper = $imageHelper;
    $this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
    .........................
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $productID = 1;
    $product = $this->_productRepositoryFactory->create()->getById($productID);
    echo $this->_imageHelper->init($product,'image')->setImageFile($product->getImage())->getUrl();
}
```

Comment: sir, Thanks for reply but this gives url i want path like var/www/magento/pub/media/catalog

Comment: i wand to display image in admin grid i am  using rendarar to get image

Answer (score 2):

**You can get product image path from below code**

```
    $product_id=20;  //enter product id here

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $product       = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

    $store         = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();

    $imageUrl      = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();

    $mediaUrl      =      $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

**i Hope it help**

Comment: sir, Thanks for reply but this gives url i want path like var/www/magento/pub/media/catalog

Comment: @AdarshShukla you mean media path?

Comment: yes i wand to display image in admin grid i am  using rendarar to get image

Comment: okay then use below code for media url

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $store         = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
  $mediaUrl      = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

Comment: @AdarshShukla check my updated code . $mediaUrl gives the path what you want

Comment: code gives o/p as following i wanted like var/www/magento  http://192.168.2.215/mtheme/pub/media/catalog/product/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg

Comment: @AdarshShukla  I think you asked diffrent question and you wanted diffrent things.

Try this once.

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $mediaUrl         = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
  $imageUrl      = $store->getPath('media');